# SQL VIEW (phpMyadmin) that uses functions

Tags: mysql, sql, function

Thank to your help I made a view in my database called 'people' that retrieve data using three functions called '**isUserVerified**', '**hasUserPicture**' and '**userHobbies**' from two tables called 'users' and '**user_hobbies**':

```
SELECT 
    `u`.`id` AS `id`,
    `isUserVerified`(`u`.`id`) AS `verification`,
    `hasUserPicture`(`u`.id) AS `profile_picture`,
    `userHobbies`(`h`.`user_id`) AS `hobbies` 
FROM 
    `people`.`users` u
INNER JOIN
   `people`.`user_hobbies` h
ON 
   `h`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
```

It returns the following output:

[image]

I realise that this is because I am joining on:

```
`h`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
```

But it is not what I want. For each user I want to run the tree function and return if they are verified, have a profile picture and a hobby. I am expecting 10 users with the relative information. Can you help? Thank you

Comment: What do you want your output to look like? AND can you add the functions please. BTW VIEW has a very specific meaning in sql - is your code part of a VIEW if so add the CREATE VIEW statement as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to join to `hobbies` at all.  Your functions are doing the work for you:

```
SELECT u.id,
       isUserVerified(u.id) AS verification,
       hasUserPicture(u.id) AS profile_picture,
       userHobbies(u.id) AS hobbies 
FROM people.users u;
```

Note that user-defined functions tend to slow queries down, sometimes a lot.  Functions may be a good idea in some languages, but in SQL it is better to express the logic as `JOIN`s and `GROUP BY`s.

Also, there is no reason to use backticks if the identifiers don't have "bad" characters.  Unnecessary backticks just make the query harder to write and read.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` to see all of the users, since `users` table is stated on the left of the `JOIN` keyword, and `INNER` looksup for the exact match in the condition. e.g. if there's no spesific user id inserted into the hobbies table, the related row is not returned by `INNER JOIN`.